# How to set up OS X terminal color theme?

Tags: macos, git, bash, terminal

I'm trying to set up the terminal of my computer (Mac OS X). I have watched some tips on how to set up the theme of the terminal going into preferences but it's not just changing the background colours, I need to make that when listing the files appears with different colours.

I have successfully installed Git plugin in `.bash_profile` file so when using version control it will show the branch I'm working on. I just can't get this theme thing to work as only can change the colours.

Comment: So, are you trying to change the color theme ***specifically of Git***, or are you trying to change the color theme of the terminal in general, as it relates to non-Git uses?

Comment: What do you mean in the last sentence " only can change the colours." the rat of the questions says you can't

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. As I have setup to show the git branch on the terminal using the `.bash_profile` I thought it could possibly be an issue in complement with git as it was also an issue to set up that feature. So what I just needed to do was to add a script to the `.bash_profile` so now can list the files with a different colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terminal preferences can't change directory listing colors, but you can enable then by adding the following to you `.bash_profile`.

```
declare -x CLICOLOR=1
declare -x LSCOLORS=gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
```

The colors can also be [tweaked to your taste](http://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/).

Comment: Are these from Linux or OSX?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how this is a git related question. Since you said you were trying to setup the terminal, could it just be that you are not able to change the background colour of your terminal?

Under Preferences -> Settings, the background colour is configured under the **Window** tab and not the **Text** tab - just in case you missed it that way